# Can't create files or directories that starts from 'com1' to 'com9'

Tags: files, filesystems, filenames, wine

I can't create folders or files named `'com1', 'com2', ..., 'com9'` in my extended hard drive. I'm trying to create a Wine prefix on my other drive where my games are stored, but I get some errors.

[image]

Here is a pastebin of the whole output when I run `winecfg` to a new prefix.
https://pastebin.com/SsaAFGdw

I believe it's not a permission issue since I can make directories and files. And, I also tried creating a prefix from my main boot drive, then move it to my extended hard drive, then I get errors when it's now trying to copy files named `'com1', 'com2', ..., 'com9'`.

[image]

This is how my extended drive partitioned:
[image]

`sudo WINEPREFIX='path' winecfg` also does not work, same result.

EDIT:
OS: Manjaro KDE Plasma

Output from `mount | grep /dev/sdb`:

```
/dev/sdb2 on /run/media/snich/Extended type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb4 on /run/media/snich/Games type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb3 on /run/media/snich/Personal type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: Some background info: https://youtu.be/bC6tngl0PTI

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @muru I'm not sure which screenshot I should had included as text.

Comment: The first two can be just text

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming ntfs-3g is used,`windows_names` is probably set somewhere as an option. [Seen man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ntfs-3g.8)

> OPTIONS
>
> windows_names
>
> This option prevents files, directories and extended attributes to be created with a name not allowed by windows, because
>
> - it contains some not allowed character,
> - or the last character is a space or a dot,
> - or the name is reserved.
>
> The forbidden characters
> are the nine characters " * / : < > ? \ | and those whose code is less
> than 0x20, and the reserved names are CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1..COM9,
> LPT1..LPT9, with no suffix or followed by a dot.
>
> Existing such files can still be read (and renamed).

### Edited response :

I'm currently with debian/Buster and there is a `/etc/udisks2/udisks2.conf` file containing :

> ```
> ### For the reference, these are the builtin mount options:
> # [defaults]
> [...]
> # ntfs_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,windows_names
> # ntfs_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,umask,dmask,fmask,locale,norecover,ignore_case,windows_names,compression,nocompression,big_writes
> ```

So, for debian, and probably most of their derivatives, mounting an NTFS implies using option `windows_names`. As explained in the same file (a little bit higher), you could try putting your options in a
`/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf` file. Just edit/create the file, copy those two lines, remove leading hash and remove option `windows_names`. Do everything as root, and take care of permissions.

Unmount and re-mount.

(Now, I'm not sure all this is a good advise : as Wine will act "à la" MS-Windows, this will not end to be a good thing.) This is just a feeling, not fact, and many others did proved it doesn't hurt.

Enjoy !

Comment: They really didn't like the folder called NUL I created on the file server a decade and a half ago.

Comment: `this will not end to be a good thing...` this isn't true at all. Windows supports names like `con`, `lpt` or `comX`... without any problem. It just forbid them by default for backward compatibility with DOS. You can create files with those names in Windows by [prepending \\?\ to the name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

Comment: @phuclv and Joshua are right, I just gave there a bad feeling without any proof. I edited my response.

Comment: @phuclv Just because NTFS (and Windows) supports them doesn't mean applications will. If an application tries to open your file named `COM4` without using UNC form (the `\\?\` prefix), they'll get an error. Most programs don't use UNC paths because they're not really necessary. Since OP is using Wine, the programs they use probably will have issues.

Comment: @ColeTobin: Explorer on windows doesn't use `\\?\` so ...

Comment: @ColeTobin the (GUI) apps usually open files by full path. Will an attempt to open e.g. `C:\some dir\COM4` result in an access to COM4 port?

Comment: @Ruslan yes. It’s a backwards compatibility thing. Originally, DOS didn’t support directories. Then, when it did, they wanted to make sure programs opening `COM4` (technically a relative path) would still work even if not in the root directory.

Answer (score 8):

**WINE** is emulating Windows and so must be compatible with it.  **COM*** are reserved words for com (serial) ports under MSDOS and WINDOWS.

[Microsoft help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended. For more information, see Namespaces.

Comment: That in itself doesn't explain why it won't work. These reserved names are a (1970s to 1990s) MS-DOS problem, and not at all applicable to Linux. And the NTFS file system in itself also doesn't care about these names. But you're of course right – someone added this as a "safeguard" to the Linux NTFS driver, so that you can't create a file that will later be completely unusable by windows machines.

Comment: That's how DOS was and that's how Windows is.  If you look at the link? Its dated 2022 and is for windows.  **WINE** is emulating Windows, so it has to work like Windows.

Comment: Wine is completely irrelevant to the problem at hand. Nothing here is done through a layer of wine.

Comment: His tag is wine

Comment: Yes, but wine is completely uninvolved with the problem at hand. At no point is wine the thing that refuses to create a file system entry.

Comment: sdb2..4 are ntfs formated

Comment: @user4089 yep, I think that's clear. (but that has nothing to do with wine)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Wine actually is very relevant here because OP wants to use these dirs _for Wine_. Thus even if OP decided to disable this safeguard and make these directories anyway, the end result would still be completely unusable by Wine. Sounds like an issue that's certainly worth mentioning. (Also, OP did actually try creating these dirs "through a layer of Wine" as well.)

Comment: that's how DOS was but that **isn't how Windows is**. You can create files in Windows with those names without any issue by adding the \\?\ prefix. Windows just don't allow them by default to maintain backward compatibility with DOS

Comment: @phuclv sounds like what you're saying is that it is an issue, but it has a mitigation (which many programs dont use and therefore will have problems with this issue)